# Can I use cordova-plugin-video-editor to convert video to GIF

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova project where I have to create gif images out of the videos, is it possible to do it using [cordova-plugin-video-editor](https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor), I am able to see options to transcode video to MPEG4(VideoEditorOptions.OutputFileType.MPEG4) but is there any option to create a gif in a same way something like VideoEditorOptions.OutputFileType.GIF

If not, is there a way to convert video to gif completely on the client side?

Comment: use the external js https://yahoo.github.io/gifshot/

Comment: That is not compatible with safari based browsers